# Access settings in Codeception bootstrap code

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I am upgrading tests from Codeception v2 to v4. The bootstrapping code is referenced in `acceptance.suite.yml` and loaded just fine.

Visible inside the `_bootstrap.php` file as of now there was a variable `$settings`, set by the surrounding Codeception code, that held information about all the live data, that was configured for the tests to run.

This variable is now gone. Printing `get_defined_vars()` only shows two variables set, strings that point to the current path and bootstrap file name.

How can I access the settings in bootstrapping code again?

I’ve looked at packagist, if there’d be a candidate for a split-off module, that would be of use here, but no candidate looked promising.

Edit: I’ve tried accessing the settings manually:

```
$settings = \Codeception\Configuration::suiteSettings('acceptance',
    \Codeception\Configuration::config());
```

However, this only allows me access to the “static” settings, i.e., basically as written in the according YAML files. What I need are the “final” settings, i.e., the ones after the environment is evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solved this problem by switching from a bootstrap file to an extension. Example:

In codeception.yml:

```
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Bootstrapper
```

The class is found in `lib/Bootstrapper.php` via Composer’s class list feature, `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "lib/"
        ]
    }
}
```

and looks something like this:

```php
<?php

use Codeception\Events;
use Codeception\Extension;

class Bootstrapper extends Extension {

    public static $events = [
        Events::SUITE_BEFORE => 'beforeSuite',
    ];

    public function beforeSuite() {
        $module = 'PhpBrowser';
        if ($this->hasModule('WebDriver')) {
            $module = 'WebDriver';
        }

        /* expose info, if we're in real-browser context */
        define('IS_REAL_BROWSER', $module === 'WebDriver');

        /* make sure the helper functions are loaded */
        require_once __DIR__.'/../tests/acceptance/_helpers.php';
    }
}
```